# MercadoPago: Error al configurar la URL para notificaciones IPN (Bad Status)

Tags: mercadopago

Estuve trabajando con un *Basic Checkout* de *MarcadoPago* en modo *SandBox*, sin ningún problema. Todo el circuito de compra funciona bien incluyendo las notificaciones (*IPN*).

Cuando quiero pasar a modo *Producción*, *MercadoPago* arroja un error al intentar configurar la *URL* para notificaciones (aquí: https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/ipn-notifications) en la cuenta real.

Siempre arroja:

> La *URL* ingresada no responde un *HTTP status* correcto. Debe responder 200 o 201.

Sin embargo, la misma *URL* funciona perfecto para el usuario *TEST*. He cambiado el  `client_id` y el `client_secret` en el código que se ejecuta al recibir la *IPN* para que se correspondan con el usuario real (una cuenta vendedor real de *MercadoPago*) pero no hay caso, no me deja configurar la *URL*.

Answer (score 2):

Mercado Pago manda tanto las notificaciones como la comprobación de https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/ipn-notifications por **POST** así que deberías poder probar que devuelva un status **200** o **201** haciendo por consola de linux:

`curl -I http://dominio.com/ipn-mercado-pago -X POST`

Answer (score 0):

Revisa cómo está hecho el *plugin* de pago de *WooCommerce*. Aquí hay uno hecho para Chile, no es oficial pero funciona.

https://cl.wordpress.org/plugins/ecommerce-mercadopago-chile/installation/

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia. Lo estuve revisando y el código para procesar las IPN es el mismo que tenía yo al principio (que me funcionaba bien en Sandbox pero no en Producción). Luego lo cambié por el nuevo que indica MP en su documentación, levemente distinto, pero tampoco funciona en modo producción.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar haciendo una petición a la página de tus notificaciones desde la terminal:

```
curl -I http://mi-url.com/mi-enlace-notificaciones
```

Revisa si te está mandando un HTTP 200 o 201, en mi caso me mandaba HTTP 301, y es que el WordPress me lo estaba redirigiendo, tuve que solucionar eso. Si este es tu caso, entonces tienes que hacer una exclusión de redirección en tu `.htaccess`.

Otra cosa que podrías probar es meter la URL sin `HTTPS`, eso igual me daba problema a mi.

Espero que funcione.

Comment: Gracias Roel por la sugerencia. Costó bastante pero logré solucionar el problema. MercadoPago da un ejemplo de funcionamiento de código para procesar la notificación que (así como viene) funciona bien en modo _SandBox_ pero no en _Producción_. Hay que reducirlo al mínimo (quitar todo prácticamente), configurar la URL y luego sí, volver a subir el código completo.

Comment: Eh, no suena muy sano dejar de usar HTTPS. Y para @dgAlef, por favor indica cuál fue la solución: escribe una respuesta y márcala aceptada (o acepta alguna de las respuestas si es lo que se debe hacer cuando se tenga tu mismo problema)

Comment: @Alfabravo Esto es del 2017, en ese año esa era la única solución (lamentablemente). Desconozco si ahorita ya funciona como debería.

Comment: @RoelMagdaleno tienes razón. Revivieron la pregunta con una respuesta-no respuesta y no vi que esta respuesta era tan vieja :/